# inno setup uninstaller in system32 Directory

Tags: .net, vb.net, inno-setup

On my innosetup file I use following code to place **unins000.exe** in system32 direcotry. it work correctly on 32bit PC. But on a 64bit PC not place unis000.exe in system32 directory. I want to place that exe in system32 directory because I want to launch uninstaller though my vb.net application. how can I fix this?

```
UninstallFilesDir={sys}\MY APP
```

here is my vb code

```
Dim sysFolderPath As String = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.System)
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(sysPath & "\MY APP\unins000.exe")
```

Comment: That's not smart at all. Imagine that someone will do the same and store their own uninstaller into this global directory. What is worse, it is the system directory, where no one but system should write (exception is for shared libraries). If you would deploy your application in a *default* way, the uninstaller would be in the same directory as the application which might be even easier for you to handle in your app. Why did you decide to put it elsewhere ? P.S. the uninstaller path can be determined through registry (by your setup's `AppId`).

Comment: @I understood. but I really need to do this. if you can explain why it not working on 64bit os I'm very appreciate

Comment: I don't think so, but you have been warned :) Application data might have been a better place, but never mind. Why it happens is described e.g. right in the `{sys}` constant reference, *On 64-bit Windows, by default, the System32 path returned by this constant maps to the directory containing 32-bit system files, just like on 32-bit Windows.* There is also mentioned how to override this, by [enabling 64-bit mode](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=32vs64bitinstalls) (just note that all other things using redirector will be affected as well, e.g. Program Files folder, registry).

Comment: @TLama Thank you. (Application data folder will be a nice idea)